# Creating shading legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, mapping

I want to create a legend next to my map in QGIS. Instead of the classes as legend entries (first picture), I want to add shading as shown in the second one.

I found this workaround ["Create a Gradient Color Ramp Legend for Continuous Datasets in QGIS"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Egc1jaPGg5k) on YouTube. But is there a smarter way?

[image]

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the data type: raster or vector?

Comment: is all vektor data @ahmadhanb

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way of doing it from a vector layer, however, what you can do is rasterise it, and get the same colour gradient for the raster.
You can use this layer's style in the print composer for your key, and hide the key element for the vector layer.

Another approach would be to keep it in vector format, and adapt [this tutorial - for rasters](https://ecodiv.earth/post/legend-for-continuous-raster-in-qgis-composer/) for a vector layer. The process is pretty much the same. This was a very quick attempt using a point layer. I haven't put in the indicator lines - If you've used a line layer, this should be really easy.

[image: My very quick version]

The divisions on the scale are terrible, I know!